# Facebook is scraping page before it should, making its preview a 404

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, addthis

Facebook is scraping our pages before the page is exposed to the public and therefore showing our 404 message as its preview. This problem is resolved by using facebook's debugger which performs a new page scrape. We use add this for our social buttons.

We allow the pages to be previewed internally before being exposed. But I am confident that no one is sharing a page before its public.

Does add this automatically request a page scrape? Will viewing a page with add this on it make facebook scrape the page even if no one shares anything?

We have two add this classes in use:

addthis_toolbox and addthis_button_facebook

Comment: Sounds like a question for facebook?

Comment: AddThis doesn't request FB to scrape your page, do you have anything else on the page like a FB Like button or FB discussion widget?  It's possible you have something else on the page that is triggering FB to scrape your page.